# Count on RDD giving different results

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a an RDD with more than 75 million rows and when I call `count` function on it, I get a different number everytime. My understanding was count is supposed to give the exact number.

**Edit**

Just to give an idea of the data, the structure is something like this

```
Userid: 1  
Date: 8/15/2015  
Location: Building 1  
...  
Date 8/1/2015  
Location: Building 5  
...  

Userid: 2  
Date: 7/30/2015  
Location: Building 10 
...
Date: 6/1/2015  
Location: Building 3 
...
```

Partition key: `Userid`
Clustering key: `Date` `ORDER BY DESC`

Spark version: 1.2.2
Data is from Cassandra
API used is Scala
Spark Cassandra connector version 1.2.2
I have just read the data from Cassandra and used map to get just the `Userid` and `Location`.

Comment: Is your underlying data source changing? Each run hits the datasource unless it's cached.

Comment: data source is same..
I am using spark shell, dont know if that makes any difference

Comment: It is probably a silly question but are you sure this is a static database? I mean there are no other operations while you work with Spark.

Comment: yes I am very sure that this is a static database and no other operations are performed while I am working

Comment: If you get count from the Cassandra itself using cqlsh or something else, is this count also different each time you request it?

Comment: i get timeouts on cqlsh as count(*) is a very expensive query, haven't tried increasing the timeout though

Comment: Please show the code you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using read consistency level Local_One and using Quorum consistency resolved the issue. 
The underlying issue was that we had a high mutation drop count for one of our nodes.